# Take the sum of all columns and create a frequency plot of top higher frequencies

Tags: r

From a dataframe like this

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), google = c(1,1,0), amazon = c(1,1,0), yahoo = c(0,0,1))
```

how is it possible to ignore the first column id and  take the sum of all columns and create a frequency plot of top higher frequencies (top 2)?

Comment: Is it row sums or column sums?

Comment: @RuiBarradas column sums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `transmute` to get the `rowSums` of the columns except the 'id', then with `ggplot/geom_col`, get the bar plot of the `top_n` (n = 2) elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
    transmute(id = factor(id), Sum = select(., -id) %>%
               rowSums) %>%
    top_n(2) %>%
    ggplot(aes(id, Sum)) +
          geom_col()
```

[image]

The above was based on 'id', if it is based on the company

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>%
    top_n(2) %>%
    ggplot(aes(name, Sum)) +
        geom_col()
```

[image]

In the newer version of `dplyr`, instead of `top_n`, we can use `slice_max`

```
df1 %>%
    transmute(id = factor(id), Sum = select(., -id) %>%
               rowSums) %>%
    slice_max(Sum, n = 2) %>%
    ggplot(aes(id, Sum)) +
          geom_col()
```

Comment: What can I do for an error like this: Error: `NULL` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @Nathalie is this based on the same dataset.  Do you have the column `class` `factor` or `numeric`.  In the example, it is `numeric` for columns 'amazon' et.c.  Can you check `str(yourdata)`

Comment: No it is the real dataset I have and they are the column names which have some character

Comment: @Nathalie I meant the column types.  it should be numeric to do the `sum`

Comment: @Nathalie if the column is `factor`, you can convert to `numeric` after the `pivot_longer` step i.e. `%>% mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>% group_by(name) %>%`

Answer (score 2):

Use `colSums` to get the frequencies by column, sort and keep the bottom 2. Pass the result to `barplot`. All in one code line.

```
barplot(tail(sort(colSums(df1[-1])), 2))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), 
                  google = c(1,1,0), 
                  amazon = c(1,1,0), 
                  yahoo = c(0,0,1))
```